# Link isnt working when positioned with a background image?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I've got this link

```
<a href="/Admin/Product/Brands" class="newButton"></a>
```

Without the class attribute and a little bit of text, the link works fine, but when I add the class to apply the background image and position the button, the link stops working. It gives no errors in the firefox console either. Any ideas? Heres my css rule for this:

```
a.newButton
    {
        margin: 5px;
        position:relative;
        left: 310px;
        top: -32px;
        display:block;
        height: 32px;
        width: 32px;
        background-image: url(Images/add-icon.png);
    }
```

This is in an ASP.NET MVC2 application, I am using the latest version of jquery (1.4.1) and this link is placed inside of a jQuery tab container, inside of a dialog.

Comment: It *looks* like maybe the other attributes, namely the negative top position may be placing it outside of a clickable area, have you tried removing the positioning and seeing if it's clickable then?

Comment: Yep, that did it. I removed the top: -32px; and the link works great. Now, how should I position it?

Comment: Why not use `<button>` and style that?

Comment: Because it didn't occur to me that I could do that? Ill give it a shot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nick Craver had it right when he suggested the negative positioning value was moving the image outside of the clickable area. I used margin-top: -32 instead to move it back to where it was. The link is now clickable. Thanks to everyone for their suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try a high z-index for a.newButton ?

Maybe there is something in front of the Button.